# how to display XML response from AJAX request in a PRE tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I am using jquery to make an AJAX request to a web service which responds with XML:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $uri,
    dataType: "xml",
    async: false,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    complete: function(xmlResponse) {
        $("#preForXMLResponse").html(xmlResponse);
    }
});
```

I want to display the XML response from the web service in a HTML page inside PRE tag. But the code above does not work. How can I change the XML response to a string and display it inside PRE tag?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $uri,
    dataType: "xml",
    async: false,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    success: function(xmlResponse) {
        $("#preForXMLResponse").html('<pre>'+xmlResponse+'</pre>');
    }
});
```

Comment: xmlResponse is [object Object]. So all I get in the pre tag is [object Object]. I want the XML as string there.

Comment: Use the `xml` property `xmlResponse.xml`

Comment: xmlResponse is not a string, so it will not work. Web service outputs true XML with applciation/xml mime type.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: $uri,
         dataType: "xml",
         async: false,
         contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
         complete: function(xmlResponse) {

                // So you can see what was wrong...
                console.log(xmlResponse);
                console.log(xmlResponse.responseText);

              $("#preForXMLResponse").text(xmlResponse.responseText);
         }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data though an HTML encode function like: http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

```
$("#preForXMLResponse").html(HTMLEncode(xmlResponse.xml));
```

Note that `HTMLEncode` is a pseudo function just to clarify my answer and must be changed to a function name like the one from the link above, aside with its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/static/css/xml/xmlname.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml){
     //now you can use of your response like
$("your tagName",$(this)).each(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('class'))

})

}
})
```

> Note:the XML response can be access only in success function