# How to display raw XML from ajax response?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, spring-boot

I have an API that returns either JSON or XML. I am trying to display the raw XML response from an AJAX call using jquery. I have done this successfully with the JSON response using `JSON.stringify`. When I try with XML I get undefined.

This is my JQuery AJAX code:

```
function fire_ajax_get() {
    $("#btn-list").prop("disabled", true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "films",
        accepts: {
            text: "application/xml"
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (event, xhr) {
            //var json = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">"+ JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) +"</div>";
            var xml = "<div id=\"insert-box\" class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">"+xhr.responseXML+"</div>";
            $('#listFilms').html(xml);

            $("#btn-list").prop("disabled", false);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            var feedback = "<div id=\"insert-box\" class=\"alert alert-warning\" role=\"alert\"></div>"
            $('#listFilms').html(feedback);

            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
            $("#btn-list").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
}
```

The commented out line above works just fine for JSON (variable name has been changed) and outputs the following in an HTML `div`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Into The Wild",
        "year": "1997",
        "genre": "Drama/Adventure",
        "director": "Sean Penn"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Titanic",
        "year": "2007",
        "genre": "Drama/Disaster",
        "director": "James Cameron"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Rise of the Footsoldier",
        "year": "2008",
        "genre": "Drama/Docudrama",
        "director": "Julian Gilbey"
    }
]
```

For the XML I just get `undefined` as output

If I change the code to say

```
success: function (data) {
        var xml = "<div id=\"insert-box\" class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">"+data+"</div>";
        $('#listFilms').html(xml);

        $("#btn-list").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Then I get `[object Object], [object Object]...` as output.

All I am looking to do here is output the raw XML data as a String within the HTML code.

like so

```
<List>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Into The Wild</name>
        <year>1997</year>
        <genre>Drama/Adventure</genre>
        <director>Sean Penn</director>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Titanic</name>
        <year>2007</year>
        <genre>Drama/Disaster</genre>
        <director>James Cameron</director>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Rise of the Footsoldier</name>
        <year>2008</year>
        <genre>Drama/Docudrama</genre>
        <director>Julian Gilbey</director>
    </item>
<List>
```

Where am I going wrong? I have read the jquery docs (https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) and looks like I am doing it correctly. I have searched for an XML.Stringify but to no avail.

Any tips would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: This looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522073/how-to-display-xml-response-from-ajax-request-in-a-pre-tag

Comment: probably a content type mismatch or the server not sending the correct header for content type

Comment: Add `dataType:'text'` to prevent the internal parser converting it to an xml document object

Comment: if you get `Object object` you are not resolving the promise. also, you don't need to stringify the XML and refer to the response xml body as res.text();

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately dataType:'text' output the data as plain text. I need it outputting as raw XML with the tags included. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Basic concept works fine for me here http://plnkr.co/edit/RgndHqVai44Act4Fq2pI?p=info

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry to be a pain. I am able to get it to display in plain text as your example does, What I want to do is display in it XML. Exactly as it is in your data.xml file. I literally want to take the XML from the response and display it as <films><film><id>1</id>.....</films>. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to see the tags as text? Like `&lt;films&gt;` would produce? Maybe this is what you want? http://plnkr.co/edit/zJQ8nMIzqRoDU338Qwc1?p=preview

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`, want xml send xml

Answer (score 0):

Reading your questions and the comments about it it seems that you have an issue with displaying `<` and `>` characters. In Javascript you can achieve it via:

```
escape('<test>somecontent</test>')
```

of course, you can use your own XML here.

Answer (score 0):

add the xml directly to you ajax https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> "`dataType` (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
>   JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
>   script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available
>   types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success
>   callback) are:
>
> "xml": Returns a XML document that can be processed via jQuery.

so put

```
dataType:"xml",
```

not

```
 accepts: {
            text: "application/xml"
        },
```

now just accept the xml

```
 success: function (xmldata) {
```

Now with all that, I show how to put the xml in as text.

```js
function dothings() {
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "films",
      dataType: "xml",
      cache: false
    })
    .done(function(dataxml, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      var xml = "<div id='insert-box' class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>" + dataxml + "</div>";
      $('#listFilms').text(xml);
      $("#btn-list").prop("disabled", false);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      var feedback = "<div id='insert-box' class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'>" + textStatus + "</div>"
      $('#listFilms').html(feedback);
      console.log("ERROR : ", errorThrown);
      $("#btn-list").prop("disabled", false);
    });
}
// just to show the xml ust .text
let x = `<List>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Into The Wild</name>
        <year>1997</year>
        <genre>Drama/Adventure</genre>
        <director>Sean Penn</director>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Titanic</name>
        <year>2007</year>
        <genre>Drama/Disaster</genre>
        <director>James Cameron</director>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Rise of the Footsoldier</name>
        <year>2008</year>
        <genre>Drama/Docudrama</genre>
        <director>Julian Gilbey</director>
    </item>
<List>`;
$('#listFilms').text(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listFilms">empty</div>
```